# My printer has paper shreds stuck inside

Tags: inkjet-printer, epson-ecotank

How can I remove a small piece of torn paper from my Epson ET-2800 printer?

I have followed the instructions for the printer but still have a small piece of paper stuck inside.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

Find a plastic sheet that is stiff enough to push the paper.
**But note:** The plastic sheet still needs to be thin enough to pass **freely** (with no resistance) through the printer in the same manner as a paper.

Then push the sheet through the printer and onto the paper piece, only nudging it, **little at a time**, to **avoid wedging it in even harder**.

If it still wedges, create a **sharp** edge on the plastic sheet and use that as a cutting tool.